# How to lock sidebar menu hidden when refresh page

Tags: javascript, html, css, sidebar

I have a sidebar menu that has been successfully hidden and shown. When the sidebar menu is hidden and I refresh the page or browser, the hidden sidebar menu will return to its original appearance, not in the position when it was hidden. The question is how to lock so that the sidebar menu display remains in a hidden position. I've tried several times using javascript but it still fails. Please help thank you.

```
.sidebar {
height: 100%;
width: 250px;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
z-index: 1000;
background-color: var(--sidebar-color);
color: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
transition: all 0.5s ease;
overflow-y: auto;
/* hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
-ms-overflow-style: none;
scrollbar-width: none;
```

}

```
.sidebar.expand {
width: 65px;
```

}

```
var btnToggle = document.querySelector("#btnToggle");
var sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");

btnToggle.onclick = function() {
    sidebar.classList.toggle("expand");

}
```

[image]

[image: when refresh page]

Comment: If you want it to be persistent, you need to use `localStorage` to store the state of the sidebar. Then, when the page reloads, you can read the state from localStorage, and set the class accordingly.

Comment: `Window.localStorage.setItem('displaySidebar', true);` to set it and `Window.localStorage.getItem('displaySidebar');` to get it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to be persistent, you need to use `localStorage` to store the state of the sidebar. Then, when the page reloads, you can read the state from `localStorage`, and set the class to the sidebar accordingly.

Untested code below:

```js
var btnToggle = document.querySelector("#btnToggle");
var sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");

// When the page loads, use localStorage to set the initial class

if(localStorage.getItem("expand") && localStorage.getItem("expand") == "true"){
  sidebar.classList.add("expand");
}

btnToggle.onclick = function() {
  sidebar.classList.toggle("expand");
  localStorage.setItem("expand", sidebar.classList.contains("expand"));
}
```

I created a [minimal code pen](https://codepen.io/johnedvard/pen/abJYOyE?editors=1111) to illustrate how it works. I also included the slide-in-out animation you mentioned in the comments.

Comment: I've tried what you mean but the slide or move is showing. What I want is that the sidebar menu doesn't appear to move

Comment: You could create new css classes to handle the transition for the slide-in and slide-out animations. Then, you can remove and add those classes only in `btnToggle.onclick`. The `expand` class can be used for the sidebar's state only, not the animaiton. Just take out the `transition: all 0.5s ease;` from `sidebar` and put it in the `slide-in`, `slide-out` class. I think that should do it.

Comment: I tried deleting the transition but it still seems to move

Comment: I created a minimal CodePen to illustrate the slide-in-out technique I was talking about: https://codepen.io/johnedvard/pen/abJYOyE?editors=1111 Maybe you are using `transition:` other places in your code? I didn't include the localStorage part in the pen though.

Comment: @Syahrir I included the above pen to use `localStorage` as well. I also adjusted it a little, and you only need one `slide-in-out` class which you can append _only_ when clicking the button. Then, the sidebar shouldn't animate.